# AGK shader not working: position should be relative to sprite center, how to fix it?

Tags: glsl, shader

I need help with calculating the cooordinates with a burning sprite pixel shader. The below shader works but the problem is, the flame created around the edge is repeated by the outline size when what i need is the uv to calculate new positioning for all of the outlined area. I hope that makes sense so it will look like a sprite on fire.

```
uniform sampler2D texture0; 
varying mediump vec2 uvVarying;
varying mediump vec4 colorVarying;
uniform vec2 agk_resolution;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float outlineSize;
uniform float Percentage;


float snoise(vec3 uv, float res)
{
    const vec3 s = vec3(1e0, 1e2, 1e3);
    
    uv *= res;
    
    vec3 uv0 = floor(mod(uv, res))*s;
    vec3 uv1 = floor(mod(uv+vec3(1.), res))*s;
    
    vec3 f = fract(uv); f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);

    vec4 v = vec4(uv0.x+uv0.y+uv0.z, uv1.x+uv0.y+uv0.z,
                  uv0.x+uv1.y+uv0.z, uv1.x+uv1.y+uv0.z);

    vec4 r = fract(sin(v*1e-1)*1e3);
    float r0 = mix(mix(r.x, r.y, f.x), mix(r.z, r.w, f.x), f.y);
    
    r = fract(sin((v + uv1.z - uv0.z)*1e-1)*1e3);
    float r1 = mix(mix(r.x, r.y, f.x), mix(r.z, r.w, f.x), f.y);
    
    return mix(r0, r1, f.z)*2.-1.;
}





void main()
{
    vec4 finalColor;    
    vec2 pixelSize =vec2(1.0)/agk_resolution;
    vec4 pixel_color = texture2D(texture0, uvVarying);
    vec2 p=vec2 (uvVarying-center);
    finalColor=pixel_color;     
    if (pixel_color.a <= 0.75)
    {
        pixel_color = colorVarying;
        pixel_color.a =0;
    float color = 3.0 - (3.*length(2.*p));
           
        for (float x = -ceil(outlineSize); x <= ceil(outlineSize); x++)
        {
            for (float y = -ceil(outlineSize); y <= ceil(outlineSize); y++)
            {
           //vec3 coord = vec3(atan(p.x,p.y)/6.2832+.5, length(p)*.4, .5);
        
                //vec2 cen=center;
        //cen=center+vec2(x,y);
        //p=vec2 (texture2D(texture0, uvVarying + vec2(x*pixelSize.x, y*pixelSize.y)).xy-center);
        //vec3 coord = vec3(atan(p.x,p.y)/6.2832+.5, length(p)*.4, .5);
                    
        vec4 tex= texture2D(texture0, uvVarying + vec2(x*pixelSize.x, y*pixelSize.y));           
                if (tex.a == 0.0 || (x==0.0 && y==0.0))
                    continue;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)

        {        
            float power = pow(2.0, float(i));  
            //vec3 coord=vec3(atan(tex.x,tex.y)/6.2832+.5, length(tex)*.4, .5)+vec3 (x,y,1.0);
            vec3 coord = vec3(atan(p.x,p.y)/6.2832+.5, length(p)*.4, .5)+vec3 (x,y,1.0);

  
                    //vec3 coord = vec3(atan(p.x,p.y)/6.2832+.5, length(p)*.4, .5);
            //float offset= (colorVarying.a / (pow(x,2.0)+pow(y,2.0) + outlineSize * 20.0)*(Percentage * 0.01));
            //vec3 coord = vec3(atan(p.x+offset,p.y+offset)/6.2832+.5, length(p)*.4, .5);
            pixel_color += (1.5 / power) * snoise(coord + vec3(0.,-time*.05, time*.01), power*16.);
                    pixel_color.a = min(pixel_color.a,1.0); 
        }
        if (pixel_color.a > 0.75)
        {
                finalColor=vec4(color,pow(max(color,0.),2.)*0.4,pow(max(color,0.),3.)*0.15,1.0); 
        }
            }
        }
    }
    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
}
```

ive tried making changes to the below command with only worse results

```
`vec3 coord = vec3(atan(p.x,p.y)/6.2832+.5, length(p)*.4, .5)+vec3 (x,y,1.0);`
```

ideally i want this effect bordered around the sprite using the shader
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmQdj.png)

Thankyou for anyhelp anyone can offer